# How do you solve this optimization constraint?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

A prettier description of the problem (written in Latex) can be found at http://i62.tinypic.com/24diqmr.jpg

Below is the text description:

Given a list of non-negative weights `w[i]` (for i=1 to d). We have the following function:

```
F = (w[1].x[1] + w[2].x[2] + ... + w[d-1].x[d-1])/w[d]
```

where `x[i] for i=1 to d` are already given and may be negative.

For each I, we know the range of weights, e.g., `w[i] >= min[i]` and `w[i] <= max[i]` where `min[i]` and `max[i]` are given for each i.

Furthermore, we know that the sum of all weights is 1, i.e., `w[1] + w[2] + ... + w[d] = 1`.

We need to find `w[i]` for each i=1 to d such that F is minimized.

How do we solve this problem? I am new to linear programming and, in fact, I am not sure if this is a linear optimization problem or not.

Comment: doesn't look very linear with the division by a decision variable.

Comment: Josilber's answer is a way to go, and, assuming that your weights are non-negative, line-search should be quite efficient.  Otherwise, this is a fractional program, and the [Charnes-Cooper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming) transformation can make it linear. This way you need to solve a single linear program.

Comment: A nonlinear optimizer like
[LBFGS-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS)
can easily minimize hundreds of variables, and be up and running in no time.
(The -B is for box constraints, low_i <= var_i <= high_i.)
Add a penalty term like `10^6 (1 - sum)^2` to your objective.
Bytheway, math.stackexchange.com does Tex in questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you do not have a linear programming problem because you divide by one of the decision variables, `w[d]`, in the objective. However, since there is only one troublesome variable, we won't have to work too hard to obtain linear programs.

Consider for a moment that `w[d]` is fixed to some constant `c`. Then the optimal value of `F` can be obtained by minimizing `(w[1].x[1] + w[2].x[2] + ... + w[d-1].x[d-1]) / c` subject to all bounding constraints on the `w[i]` variables and subject to the constraint `w[1] + w[2] + ... + w[d-1] = 1-c`. Since `c` is a constant, this is a linear programming problem that can be solved with standard linear programming software. Let's call the objective value of this model `F(c)`.

All that remains is to identify the `c` value satisfying `min[d] <= c <= max[d]` such that `F(c)` is minimized. This is a 1-dimensional optimization problem that can be solved with [line search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search); your favorite programming language probably has a classical line search algorithm already implemented, and if not you should be able to implement one on your own without too much trouble.

To conclude, you can solve your problem by performing a line search, for each function evaluation solving a linear programming problem.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. 

Can we minimize (w[1].x[1] + w[2].x[2] + ... + w[d-1].x[d-1])/c using the following algorithm instead of LP?

Total weight we need to apply is 1-c.  We first allocate weight min[i] to each of w[i] (for i=1 to d-1) because this is a constraint. Let R denote the remaining weight after allocating min[i] for each i.

Assume x[1] <= x[2] <= ... <= x[d-1] (if not, we can sort so). Starting from i=1, we allocate w[i] to its maximum possible value (e.g., depending on max[i] and the remaining weight R to be applied). We stop when R has been exhausted.

Comment: Also, it appears that line-search gives an approximate solution only. Is it possible to obtain a lower bound on the minimum value instead (and hopefully more efficiently)?

Thanks

Comment: @Cheema As I see it, both of your comments on this answer are really follow-on questions that merit entirely new questions on Stack Overflow. I would encourage you to ask any additional questions you have with the "Ask Question" button so the whole community has a chance to see them and answer.